# Macbook hangs when removing HDMI cable

Tags: hardware, screen, performance, hdmi

I have a very frustrating problem: when I remove the HDMI cable from my MacBook Pro (i.e. to disconnect my external monitor, and move about with the laptop), the screen just refuses to wake up when I open the lid. It doesn't react to the keyboard or mouse. It's a 2014 model, 13" Retina with Integrated Graphics.

What can I do to solve this problem of the MacBook hanging?

It goes via an HDMI -> DVI adapter, in case that's relevant.

[image]

Comment: 10.12.3. What model details do you need beyond what's in the question? I don't put it to sleep first, no, just pull out the cable.

Comment: I have also tried plugging in a USB mouse. The mouse itself didn't wake the screen up, but its light *was* on, indicating the computer has power at the very least.

Comment: For 2014, there are two models, one with integrated graphics and the other with a second GPU.

Comment: I think it's integrated: Intel Iris 1536 MB

Comment: Try putting it to sleep first to see if that has any effect.  Also, I'm not a big fan of changing video formats (HDMI to DVI); I prefer to keep everything native.  Is your monitor cable of using HDMI or DisplayPort?

Comment: I'll definitely try putting it to sleep first. It doesn't have HDMI, unfortunately, but there is a DisplayPort input (it's a Dell U2412M).

Comment: I have this problem too! Genius at the Apple Store didn't know what to say when I brought it in, tried a full wipe then restore from Time Machine backup which has helped so far.

Comment: Can you add a picture of the About My Mac screen to your question (Menubar -> Apple Logo -> About My Mac -> Overview)?

Comment: That's kind of an extreme option, but it's good to know that it might help, as a last resort. Also 'good' to know that someone else has this problem! I'm currently waiting on a delivery of a DisplayPort cable, which I'm hoping might help. Finally, I'm thinking that I may be able to workaround it by opening the lid whilst it's still connected to the monitor, *then* remove the cable to the monitor. I think that routine might help.

Comment: maybe the Mac thinks its still connected. Try CMD+F1, which switches mirror mode on and off.

Comment: @BobbyJack I have the same screen size, same mid-2014 model, same i5 chipset, same 16 GB of RAM, same Intel Iris graphics, and same version of macOS Sierra (10.12.3) on my affected Mac. Coincidence?

Answer (score 2):

Reverting to El Capitan fixed the problem for me with a mid 2014 rMBP, so it sounds like a Sierra bug. Hoping that the 10.12.4 release fixes it.

Comment: Indeed, this is clearly a bug with macOS Sierra on the 2014-series rMBPs (probably only the ones with Intel Iris integrated graphics).